# How avoid Broken Pipe with Sqlalchemy & MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to move from SQLite to MySQL - and I am almost there. However, I all the time encounter one problem, that plagues me regardless if I am connecting to my local MySQL db, or the one hosted on Google Cloud. Have anyone had the same issue.

This is the code I use to append pandas dataframe to the table

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
connection = create_engine(f"mysql+mysqlconnector://{user}:{pw}@{host}/{db}")
tablename = 'TABLENAME'
df.to_sql(tablename, connection, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

The pandas table is not very large, a few tens of rows at a time.

Every now and then I get this error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError) 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'serverip:port', system error: 32 Broken pipe
```

So far I have been using sqlite3 package for SQLite - do you think it is sqlalchemy or MySQL which is the problem?

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html?highlight=disconnects#dealing-with-disconnects

Comment: Thank you. I am familiar with that. But my question is - why is this not working as smoothly with sqlalchemy & mysql as it does with sqlite?